# pass data form HTML to JS valid JSON data

Tags: jquery, html, json

i have form edit data and my input:

```
<input type="text" id="mySelectID" data-initvalue="[{"id":"1","text":"Value 1"},{"id":"2","text":"Value 2"}]" name="category" />
```

I have js function: http://jsfiddle.net/87xpB/54/

```
AjaxCombo("mySelectID", "ajax.php?get=categories", "multival");
```

i view console:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
```

how valid JSON in html pass to JS

thankyou

Comment: The attribute `data-initvalue` has formatting errors

Comment: You'll have to scape the quotes in your `data-initvalue`

Comment: i have error in `data-initvalue` and i try format it thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to html encode your JSON string. Then your tag looks like:

```
<input type="text" id="mySelectID" data-initvalue="[{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Value 1&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Value 2&quot;}]" name="category" />
```

Comment: i have use your code and change form `$(elm).attr("data-initvalue");` to `$(elm).data.("data-initvalue");`. result console is `undefined` thankyou

Comment: @cnttlc You would need to use `$(elm).data('initvalue');`

Answer (score 1):

Change the quotes around the data (from double quotes to single quotes)

```
<input type="text" id="mySelectID" data-initvalue='[{"id":"1","text":"Value 1"},{"id":"2","text":"Value 2"}]' name="category" />
```

Also, looking at the fiddle you're not using the selector correctly, it should be:

```
AjaxCombo("#mySelectID", "ajax.php?get=categories", "multival");
//         ^here
```

And another thing, don't use `attr` for `data`, jQuery has a built in method for this called [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/):

```
// From this:
$(elem).attr("data-initvalue");
// To this:
$(elem).data("initvalue");
```

Comment: thankyou. My code put in php: `echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sl2\" id=\"categories\" data-initvalue=\"'[{"id":"1","text":"Value 1"},{"id":"2","text":"Value 2"}]'\" data-placeholder=\"Chọn một danh mục tương ứng cho video..\" style=\"width: 600px !important;\" />";` if change to `data-initvalue=\"[{\"id\":\"1\",\"text\":\"Value 1\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"text\":\"Value 2\"}]\"` it show error `"[{"`

Comment: Sorry if don't follow you, using `'[{"id":"1","text":"Value 1"},{"id":"2","text":"Value 2"}]'` does not work? The error occurs in JavaScript? which line?

Comment: thankyou. it show error console `syntax error` at `'[{"id":"1","text":"Value 1"},{"id":"2","text":"Value 2"}]'` and i change `$(elem).data("data-initvalue");`